# ThreadPoolExecutor Running Application

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

Billing class has all the logic related with Country wise billing. It takes result from database and then bills users. Billing class implements Runnable. I want to execute Billing parallelly according to country parameter such that huge number of users (5 million+) are billed very fast. Now it takes hours and hours to finish.

I am trying to implement ThreadPoolExecutor for execution of Billing class but am confused how to?? What is the difference in the following OR am I doing something wrong? Please suggest!! There are altogether 20 countries but I am pasting here only 5.

```
 //for 20 countries  ThreadPoolExecutor (20,20,20.......)????

ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(5, 5, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS, 
new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(10), new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());

executor.execute(new Billing("UK")); 
executor.execute(new Billing("USA")); 
executor.execute(new Billing("Germany")); 
executor.execute(new Billing("Spain")); 
executor.execute(new Billing("Italy"));
```

OR

```
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(5, 5, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS, 
new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(10), new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
for(int i=0;i<5;i++) // for 20 countries   i<20??
{    

   executor.execute(new Billing("UK")); 
   executor.execute(new Billing("USA")); 
   executor.execute(new Billing("Germany")); 
   executor.execute(new Billing("Spain")); 
   executor.execute(new Billing("Italy")); 
}

while (! executor.isTerminated()) {
   try{
      executor.awaitTermination(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   }catch(InterruptedException iE)
   {
      iE.printStackTrace();
      System.out.println("Executor Exception: "+ iE);
   }
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Are you just asking about whether or not to use that `for` loop? It isn't entirely obvious what you mean.

Comment: @TimBender ........... I have amended my question...

Comment: @TimBender .. I am confused in implementing ThreadPoolExecutor for executing Billing Class..   how should I implement? Do I have to use For loop inside ThreadPoolExecutor??  OR it will run all the Billing Class parallelly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop solution doesn't seem right. There is no need to execute same `Runnable` multiple times.

You are instantiating `ThreadPoolExecutor` with both `corePoolSize` and `maximumPoolSize` set to `5`, which means the executor will maintain the number of threads in the pool to `5`, even if they are idle. It also says that there can be no more than `5` threads in the pool.

With this in place, you can expect at most `5` threads running in parallel executing the tasks (`Billing` objects).

As you continue submitting `Billing` objects to `executor` with `execute` method they are added to the `ArrayBlockingQueue` provided by you. The size of this queue is `10` here. It may be possible that at some instance queue is already at its maximum capacity and can't take more tasks, in which case the task is rejected and given to the `RejectedExecutionHandler` provided in the `ThreadPoolExecutor` constructor. Its job is to handle rejected tasks with the implemented method `rejectedExecution`.

If you want to find if there were any rejected tasks you have to provide your own `RejectedExecutionHandler` instead of using the default `ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy`. You can do it with something like this:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(5, 5, 5,
        TimeUnit.SECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(10),
        new RejectedExecutionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r,
                    ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
                System.out.println("I got rejected: " + r);
                if (!executor.isShutdown()) {
                    r.run();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: @NishantShresthth..  when I tried with execute(NewBilling("Country")) Some of the Billing Class wasn't executing at all.. for example out of 20 only 16 were running...

Comment: OR I am mistaken in declaring ThreadPoolExecutor having only ArrayBlockingQueue <Runnable>(10)... Shall I make it to 20??

Comment: If your `Billing` tasks are time consuming, some of the tasks might get rejected if the queue is full at some instance. Increasing the size of the queue should be helpful in such a case.

Answer (score 1):

First: forget the loop

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++) // for 20 countries   i<20??
{    

   executor.execute(new Billing("UK")); 
   executor.execute(new Billing("USA")); 
   executor.execute(new Billing("Germany")); 
   executor.execute(new Billing("Spain")); 
   executor.execute(new Billing("Italy")); 
}
```

this loops over all billings multiple times.

The right thing to do is in the first snippet:

```
executor.execute(new Billing("UK")); 
executor.execute(new Billing("USA")); 
executor.execute(new Billing("Germany")); 
executor.execute(new Billing("Spain")); 
executor.execute(new Billing("Italy"));
```

Another error lies on the termination check:

```
while (! executor.isTerminated()) {
   try{
      executor.awaitTermination(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   }catch(InterruptedException iE)
   {
      iE.printStackTrace();
      System.out.println("Executor Exception: "+ iE);
   }
}
```

The javadoc of `Executor.awaitTermination` says:

> Blocks until all tasks have completed execution after a shutdown request,

but you never issue a shutdown request.

In your case, you could leverage the `ExecutorCompletionService` as in:

```
CompletionService<String> ecs = new ExecutorCompletionService<String>(executor);
List<String> countries= Arrays.asList("UK","USA","Germany","Spain","Italy");   
for(String country : countries) {
    ecs.submit(new Billing(country),country);
}
// wait for completion
for(int i=0;i<countries.size();i++){
      ecs.take(); // wait for next country completion
}
// all work completed, shutdown
executor.shutdownNow();
```

Comment: +1 for `but you never issue a shutdown request`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you understand how loops work.  The difference is that the second block of code would run billing 5 times on each of the listed countries.

Comment: but without using for loop..  Threadpoolexecutor wasn't executing all the 20 Billings??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about the `for` loop portion of code, it isn't obvious how that would work.

Ideally the loop would look something like this:

```
for(String country : countryCollection) {
    executor.execute(new Billing(country));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using an `enum`?

```
static class Billing implements Runnable {

  enum Country {
    UK,
    USA,
    Germany,
    Spain,
    Italy;
  }

  public Billing(Country country) {
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
  }
}
public void test() {
  ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(5, 5, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
       new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(10), 
          new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
  for ( Billing.Country country : Billing.Country.values() ) {
    executor.execute(new Billing(country));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to think about implementing this is to take a look at [The Fork/Join Framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html). This seems like it can really benefit from work steeling. For example you can break this up seemingly fairly cleanly. This will basically allow you to break up the task of billing by user or a subset of the users, opposed to having a thread which is seemingly representing a country work through all of its billing.

You can find the link to the library: [here if you are using a version of Java < 7](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/concurrency-interest/)

Comment: I am running on java 6.. fork/join is on java 7??

Comment: The library has been available for a while, I edited my response to give the link